# Is it possible to register 2 domains for the same ip?

Tags: dns, domain

Is it possible to have 2 domains point to the same website (no redirects)?

Lets say i own the domain mydomain.com and want it to point to superuser.com. When someone goes to mydomain.com they wouldnt be redirected but they would see the content of superuser.com and their browser woul still show that theyre looking at mydomain.com.

Maybe instead of pointing to superuser.com both of the domains could point to my own website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to answer your title, yes absolutely. many [sites/services can be hosted on the same IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_web_hosting_service#Name-based), with different [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#) names and owners. registering a domain name is just [registering the name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_registration). you (as registrant) can configure your DNS hosting/server to point to where ever you want. you can add many A-recs and CNAME-recs pointing to the same IP.

Digging into the body of the question however, you are failing to account for service configuration like [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) [certificates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509). Superuser.com HTTPS features cannot be used when the domain name does not match superuser.com or a listed entry in the [Subject Alternative Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_Alternative_Name) embedded in the HTTPS certificate that the web application superuser.com is configured to use. Users that try to use yourdomain.com to reach superuser.com will experience an HTTPS error.

So, you can make any name you want point to any IP you want, but there is absolutely no guarantee that the service on that IP will allow clients too cooperate with your scheme.

yes you can use multiple domains to refer to a service you own. if those services require an identifying certificate, make sure the additional names appear as SANs on the certificate you purchase/request.

Answer (score 0):

On the DNS host side, you're just setting different A or AAAA names for an IP or a CNAME pointing at one of those. ALL Your DNS server does is tell a system looking for a domain name that the domain name points at a specific IP.

Many protocols don't 'care' about the domain.

So lets say I'm running a IRC service with a web UI and say a blog, and point chat.example.com and example.com at the same IP. My DNS *client* will run a query for each domain, and tell the network stack to connect there.

You can set as many domains or subdomains to an IP and they *will* connect to that IP. Its up to the client/server negotiations to figure out how that works

My IRC client won't care if I'm connecting to chat.example.com or example.com. It'll connect to the IP and port its told to and 'just' work.

A *webserver* however can be set to different virtualhosts - and the browser will actually *include* what domain it wants to connect to. The web server will/can then serve the appropriate content for chat.You'd as such be able to get a webui for the irc service (maybe via proxying *another* service or server) or whatever you want on example.com

This is a simplified explaination of course, but yes you can.